# Windows desktop computer w/ no login screen after GoToMyPC user is done with it

Tags: windows-xp, rdp, bsod

I have a number of Windows XP SP3 machines on the domain that run GoToMyPC for remote access for contractors.  Every once in a while, the contractors will call me up and tell me that they can't log in, all they see is a blue screen (not a BSOD).  Checking the physical computer confirms this, it looks like the blue background behind the standard login "press ctrl+alt+delete..." screen w/ mouse cursor, but no "press ctrl+alt+delete..." dialog.

RDP to machine works just fine in these cases and rebooting the machine seems to solve it temporarily.  The users have been rather unhelpful as to their last actions and the blue screen issue isn't consistently repeatable.  Event log doesn't show anything unusual.  It doesn't appear to be user specific either (other than being confined to the users that run GoToMyPC).

Has anyone else run into this issue/have any idea about how to troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen before.  To fix it, I had to call Citrix to get the latest build of the GoToMyPC Host, and that took care of it.  Granted this was 6 months ago, so that build has already been released, but it couldn't hurt to call and ask.

Also, for me it was tied to when they were using the "Blank screen when connected".  Turn off that feature, and the problem went away.

Comment: have submitted a ticket with Citrix for this.  Thank you for the prompt response!